# ignore series with old in peometheus query

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have an example program that can be summarizes to the following problem:

I want to tracks amount of "balls" in a baskets. So i have a Prometheus counter for every basket that tracks amount of balls in it. lets call this counter Balls(basket_name="name"), so i have a series Balls and a label with basket name. 
Now to display total amount of balls in all baskets i do the following in promql sum(Balls), and it displays total amount of balls in basket.
Problem is that i can restart my program with different baskets every time, but query sum(Balls), will continue count "old" baskets from previous runs.

Question: How to i set the query to only count amount of "balls" in last lets say 5 minutes.?  i.e. ignore all series from before.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus will only return (and include in PromQL) queries non-stale time series. Depending on where your metrics are collected from and how, you are [at least guaranteed](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) to never see samples that are more than 5 minutes old (and possibly much sooner).

If OTOH your samples are pushed to a Pushgateway and Prometheus collects them from there, then you're more or less out of luck. AFAIK Pushgateway metrics never expire, you need to explicitly delete them when you know e.g. that the source pushing them is permanently gone.